# Problem in making multiple PDF pages with gridExtra in R

Tags: r, gridextra

I used `grid.table` from the package `gridExtra` in `R` to make a PDF report of my Stat tests outputs.
I use this code:

```
library(gridExtra)
my_text = readLines("Dunnett.txt") 
my_text2 = readLines("Shapiro-Wilk.txt") 



pdf(sprintf("Results.pdf"), width=11, height=8)
grid.table(my_text)
grid.table(my_text2)
dev.off()


#cleanup
file.remove("Dunnett.txt")
file.remove("Shapiro-Wilk.txt")
```

But the problem is that my grid.table1 and 2 overlay on each other in one page. I want them be saved in 2 different pages. 
Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(grid)
grid::grid.newpage()
```

Comment: Thanks
it worked
`grid.table(my_text)
grid.newpage()
grid.table(my_text2)`