# Grid.table: export multiple tables into one pdf

Tags: r, pdf

I am trying to display **multiple tables** using **grid.table** and **export** them in a **pdf**, but it only shows the first table. Why?

```
tbl <- matrix(1:100,nrow=10)

tbl2 <- matrix(100:1,nrow=10)

require("gridExtra")

pdf("test.pdf")
grid.table(tbl)
grid.table(tbl2)

dev.off()
```

Comment: try adding in `grid::grid.newpage()` between them (this will stop the second table geing printed on top of the first)

Comment: probably a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58333833/problem-in-making-multiple-pdf-pages-with-gridextra-in-r

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `plot.new`. You can use the following code:

```
tbl <- matrix(1:100,nrow=10)

tbl2 <- matrix(100:1,nrow=10)

require("gridExtra")

pdf("test.pdf")
grid.table(tbl)
plot.new()
grid.table(tbl2)
dev.off()
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, the second plot is shown on the second page.